# Add number to specific word in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, numbers, addition, cpu-word

I want to add number at specific word in eclipse, I mean replace "btn" and add to him number automaticly like after 1 write 2 after 3 after 4... without do it manually

```
    <Button
        android:id="+@id/btn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="+@id/btn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="+@id/btn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn"
        android:padding="10dp" />
```

like that it add number after the specific word

```
    <Button
        android:id="+@id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn1"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="+@id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn2"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="+@id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn3"
        android:padding="10dp" />
```

and if we cant with eclipse, can sombody give me a link of something like that :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible within the Eclipse editor. The only editor I could think of that might be able to do this is Sublime Text. It does allow you to highlight all instances of a word and edit them at the same time, but after some quick searching, it doesn't look like you can edit them to have increasing numbers like you want.

If there were enough instances that you wanted to change, and you felt like you might use it often, you could always write a small program that does this for you.

Comment: yes, I want because in lot of cases I need it but the problem that I cant write it because im beginner in programming, and type of program like that it so useful but I didn't find something like that ^^

Comment: if somebody know how, it with pleasure